# Trying to replace old "names" with new "names" in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have two Excel files. One of the Excel files has the new and old names in it in a random order, something like this:

```
Colum A        Colum B
apple-er3      horse-er45
alk-er43       erk-bf43
```

and it continues for around 400 rows.

The other is filled with the old names in a specific order:

```
colum A         colum B
*old name*       *old name*
```

I want to be able to translate all the old names in it with the new.

I was thinking about making a dictionary but I can't figure out a good way of writing it when there are so many names to translate. I would like to go into the Excel with the old names, copy one colum at the time and then paste it into the Python program for it to translate it all to the new names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html) quite handy for loading data from [and saving data to] spreadsheets. You could use [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to read the old and new names from the fist file and convert them into a dictionary (`tRef_dict`) as below.

**<sub>[NOTE: If your file is a CSV, use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead of `read_excel`.]</sub>**

```py
import pandas as pd

tRef_fp = 'map_old_new.xlsx' ## path to file with new&old names
tRef_dict = pd.read_excel(tRef_fp).to_dict('split')
tRef_dict = {k:v for v,k,*_ in tRef_dict['data']} # colA->new, colB->old
# tRef_dict = dict(tRef_dict['data']) # only 2 cols, colA->old, colB->new
```

- Use `pd.read_excel(tRef_fp, header=None).to_dict('split')` if the sheet doesn't have a header row (otherwise, the first row would not be included in `tRef_dict['data']`).
- With your example data, *`dict(tRef_dict['data'])`* would return

  ```py
  {'apple-er3': 'horse-er45', 'alk-er43': 'erk-bf43'}
  # 'apple-er3' will get translated to  'horse-er45'
  ```
- and *`{k:v for v,k,*_ in tRef_dict['data']}`* would return

  ```py
  {'horse-er45': 'apple-er3', 'erk-bf43': 'alk-er43'}
  # 'horse-er45' will get translated to  'apple-er3'
  ```

---

Then, you can load the file with only old names, use [`.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and `tRef_dict` to update the names, and then save the updated names with [`.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) <sup>(or [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to save to a CSV file)</sup> :

```py
old_fp = 'old.xlsx' ## path to file with old names
new_fp = 'new.xlsx' ## [can be the same as old_fp]

names_df = pd.read_excel(old_fp) #, header=None) ## if there is no header row, specify
names_df = names_df.applymap(lambda x: tRef_dict.get(x,x)) ## [update names]
names_df.to_excel(new_fp, index=False) #, header=False) ## [save updated]
```

Comment: Wow worked perfectly. Im just trying to understand how all this work. Im very new to programming. Do you mind if i ask some questions? I dont know if i should put them here or if i can send them in some sort of DM on here.

Comment: @AntonLarsson there are [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), but you need at least 20rp to send messages (and also, afaik they're not private like DMs typically are). You can ask anything about here and I'll try to answer if I can. [Btw, if the comment thread gets too long, a chatroom gets automatically generated and the link is added to the thread.]

Comment: Oh okey. So im woundering
1.  the first parts i do understand but what does this do?   
.to_dict('split')

2. I read your notes and they are well writen but this:

tRef_dict = {k:v for v,k,*_ in tRef_dict['data']}

would you mind explaining  {k:v for v,k,*_ in tRef_dict['data']}
i guess k means colume? the rest i cant figure out, especially the "data" part.

Comment: @AntonLarsson [`.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) returns the DataFrame as a dictionary, and specifying `orient='split'` tells it to form a dictionary with the index, column names and data separated into 3 lists *`{‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}`* [`data` will be a list of sub-lists, with each sub-list representing one row]

Comment: Oh okey, what is a DataFrame? is it just the csv or excel file?

and what is "index" i guess columns is just the excel colums A and B and data is the value in the cells? Or is data the rows?

Comment: A [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) is a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#intro-to-pandas) data structure for organizing 2D data (such as a table) [ view [`tRef_df`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME7wS.png) for example ].

Comment: Just like columns have names, rows have index. `data` is a list of rows in this case (**`[['apple-er3', 'horse-er45'], ['alk-er43', 'erk-bf43']]`**), but when constructing a df it can also be a dictionary of columns (like *`{'Colum A': ['apple-er3', 'horse-er45'], 'Colum B': ['alk-er43', 'erk-bf43']}`*)

Answer (score 0):

Given a CSV file that looks something like:

```
apple-er3,horse-er45
alk-er43,erk-bf43
```

you can build a dictionary that translates between the two very easily:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv') as f:
    name_trans = dict(csv.reader(f))
```

`dict()` will take an iterable of pairs (which is what a `csv.reader` of a 2-column CSV file will give you) and turn it into a dictionary where the first item is the key and the second item is the value, so the above two lines of code is all you need to build the name translation dictionary you want.

If the CSV has a header you need to skip, or if it has other columns you need to ignore, those are modifications that only represent another line or two of code; the basic strategy is the same.

Once you have `name_trans` you can do:

```
new_name = name_trans[old_name]
```

to translate any `old_name` to its corresponding `new_name`.